# head is not moving correctly when I move/rotate the head bone

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I'm trying to understand what does not work correctly on the rigging of my model,because the head is not moving correctly when I move/rotate the head bone. I attached a short video to show you. Very thanks for every tip that you want to give me.

[my situation](http://sendvid.com/o2eu18r0)

You can see the result that I want to reach at minute 37.15 of the JorgeBernier5D tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCGekumdLLU

he moves the head bone and all the head moves homogeneously. It does not happen to my bird.

[image]

Comment: It seems your head bone is not connected to the neck bone, but it's hard to say without a blend file. You might want to upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com .

Comment: I added the blender file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already suspected your head bone is not connected to the neck. Besides that your whole armature is quite messy. There are many other occasions where bones aren't connected to anything (legs, feet) and many of them are redundant (in the image below I tried sorting the bones and moved them away for that purpose. I stopped at the neck ;-) ).

[image: redundant bones]

Go check your arm bones, there are layers upon layers of bones that don't serve any purpose.

I would start from scratch and slowly by creating the body armature first and then adding the facial bones to that. A good starting point to learn how to rig a character from scratch is [Darrin Lile's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2MGttB1E7U). He knows exactly what he's doing and he also has [another rigging tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQJTkiWthN8) in which he uses rigify.

It's also highly advisable to switch to octahedral and x-ray mode when working with armatures (at least until you know exactly what you are doing). It's way better to keep track of your bones and their connections.

[image]